# Is there a best way to return all values from an array of object based on the value of one of the keys. Using array.reduce or array.forEach

Tags: javascript

I am use a selection on counties to get the district and its total population per the county specified. But this is not working for all the counties rather it's happening just randomly.
I want to get the county from the select option and return the district and its total population for male and female.

This is the code

```
let selected_county = ["Lofa", "Bomi", "Bong", "River Gee", "Sinoe"];
let population =[
         { "county": "River Gee ",
            "district": "Glaro ",
            "male": 2613,
            "female": 2379
        },
        {
            "county": "River Gee ",
            "district": "Karforh ",
            "male": 3072,
            "female": 2884
        },
        {
            "county": "Lofa ",
            "district": "Nanee ",
            "male": 3421,
            "female": 2581
        },
        {
            "county": "Lofa ",
            "district": "Nyenawliken ",
            "male": 2668,
            "female": 2491
        },
        {
            "county": "Bong ",
            "district": "Nyenebo ",
            "male": 3046,
            "female": 2657
        },
        {
            "county": "Bong ",
            "district": "Potupo",
            "male": 3689,
            "female": 3648
        },
        {
            "county": "Bomi ",
            "district": "Sarbo ",
            "male": 2680,
            "female": 2640
        },
        {
            "county": "Bomi ",
            "district": "Tuobo ",
            "male": 2496,
            "female": 2372
        },
        {
            "county": "Sinoe ",
            "district": "Bodae ",
            "male": 2151,
            "female": 1388
        },
        {
            "county": "Sinoe ",
            "district": "Bokon ",
            "male": 2457,
            "female": 1916
        }]
   let district_population = { };

   population.forEach((ele)=>{
       ele.forEach((elem) => {
         if (elem.county === selected_county) { 

    //selected_county has the array of county used in the population's array

           districts_population[elem.district] = elem.male + elem.female;
   
           }
        })
    })
   console.log(districts_population);
```

Expected output:

```
"River Gee" : {{
            "district": "Karforh ",
            "male": 3072,
            "female": 2884,
             "total" : 5956
            },
            {
             "district": "Karforh ",
            "male": 3072,
            "female": 2884,
              "total": 5956
            }}
    "Lofa" :{
            {
            "district": "Nanee ",
            "male": 3421,
            "female": 2581,
             "total" : 6002
        },
        {
          "district": "Nyenawliken ",
            "male": 2668,
            "female": 2491,
            "total": 5159
        }
       }
"Bong": {{
            "district": "Nyenebo ",
            "male": 3046,
            "female": 2657,
            "total": 5159
        },
        { 
            "district": "Potupo",
            "male": 3689,
            "female": 3648,
            "total": 5159
        }
      }
"Bomi":{{
            "district": "Sarbo ",
            "male": 2680,
            "female": 2640,
            "total": 5159
        },
        {
            "district": "Tuobo ",
            "male": 2496,
            "female": 2372,
            "total": 5159
        }
      }
"Sinoe": {{ 
            "district": "Bodae ",
            "male": 2151,
            "female": 1388
            "female": 2372,
            "total": 5159
        },
        { 
            "district": "Bokon ",
            "male": 2457,
            "female": 1916
            "female": 2372,
            "total": 5159
        }
      }
```

//But this output is only happening for few counties not all

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a space after each county name, which means it won't match. Here's a quick solution...

```js
let selected_county = ["Lofa", "Bomi", "Bong", "River Gee", "Sinoe"];
let population =[
         { "county": "River Gee ",
            "district": "Glaro ",
            "male": 2613,
            "female": 2379
        },
        {
            "county": "River Gee ",
            "district": "Karforh ",
            "male": 3072,
            "female": 2884
        },
        {
            "county": "Lofa ",
            "district": "Nanee ",
            "male": 3421,
            "female": 2581
        },
        {
            "county": "Lofa ",
            "district": "Nyenawliken ",
            "male": 2668,
            "female": 2491
        },
        {
            "county": "Bong ",
            "district": "Nyenebo ",
            "male": 3046,
            "female": 2657
        },
        {
            "county": "Bong ",
            "district": "Potupo",
            "male": 3689,
            "female": 3648
        },
        {
            "county": "Bomi ",
            "district": "Sarbo ",
            "male": 2680,
            "female": 2640
        },
        {
            "county": "Bomi ",
            "district": "Tuobo ",
            "male": 2496,
            "female": 2372
        },
        {
            "county": "Sinoe ",
            "district": "Bodae ",
            "male": 2151,
            "female": 1388
        },
        {
            "county": "Sinoe ",
            "district": "Bokon ",
            "male": 2457,
            "female": 1916
        }]

selected_county.forEach(country => {
  population.forEach(el => {
    el.county == (country + " ") && console.log(el)})
})
```

Comment: Why not just use `.trim()` to correct for any errors?. If this was like 10,000 objects, that would be massively inefficient.

Comment: Hi Paul Martin, the output I gave first was just a template please see the reversed one and see what I am lacking.

Answer (score 0):

I receive an error while running the code, but I think your problem is that there are spaces at the end of the county names in `population`.

I'm not sure whether you want the full population, in an object, because your expected output is different. I just went with your expected output, but if you clear it up, I can edit my answer, to the correct output

```js
let selected_county = ["Lofa", "Bomi", "Bong", "River Gee", "Sinoe"];
let population =[
         { "county": "River Gee",
            "district": "Glaro ",
            "male": 2613,
            "female": 2379
        },
        {
            "county": "River Gee",
            "district": "Karforh ",
            "male": 3072,
            "female": 2884
        },
        {
            "county": "Lofa ",
            "district": "Nanee ",
            "male": 3421,
            "female": 2581
        },
        {
            "county": "Lofa ",
            "district": "Nyenawliken ",
            "male": 2668,
            "female": 2491
        },
        {
            "county": "Bong ",
            "district": "Nyenebo ",
            "male": 3046,
            "female": 2657
        },
        {
            "county": "Bong ",
            "district": "Potupo",
            "male": 3689,
            "female": 3648
        },
        {
            "county": "Bomi ",
            "district": "Sarbo ",
            "male": 2680,
            "female": 2640
        },
        {
            "county": "Bomi ",
            "district": "Tuobo ",
            "male": 2496,
            "female": 2372
        },
        {
            "county": "Sinoe ",
            "district": "Bodae ",
            "male": 2151,
            "female": 1388
        },
        {
            "county": "Sinoe ",
            "district": "Bokon ",
            "male": 2457,
            "female": 1916
        }]
let districts_population=population.filter(count=>selected_county.includes(count.county.trim()))

console.log(districts_population);
```